# dynamic inner join on same table in hibernate with different criteria

Tags: hibernate

I need help to write a hibernate query for an SQL query equivalent to the below query

```
    select mo2.* from ManagedObjects mo, ManagedObjects mo1, ManagedObjects 
    mo2
    Where Mo1.Type = '' And Mo1.Name Like '%%'
    And Mo.Subtype = '' And Mo.Name Like '%%'
    And mo2.subtype = '' and mo2.name like '%%'
    And Mo.Idhierarchy = Substr(Mo2.Idhierarchy,0,Length(Mo.Idhierarchy))
    And Mo1.Idhierarchy = Substr(Mo.Idhierarchy,0,Length(Mo1.Idhierarchy));
```

Could anyone suggest me what's the best way to write.
Also the inner joining of tables will change based on the user input criteria..

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this query?

Comment: I need to query the same table with different search conditions and there is a hierarchy maintained on the values in table.
Some of the values are linked through hierarchy. child objects have hierarchy values taken from parent followed by their own ids.

The conditions written in where clause of the above query are got through user input and the number of input can vary and so are the values.